# In playwright, how can we assert if an icon is visible in UI?

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

**Problem** - In playwright I need to find the way to assert if the icon below is visible in UI or not.

```
   <div data-testid="icon-container>
     <div class="icon"></div>
    </div>

.icon {
 background-image: url("some url")
}
```

Currently I am asserting it like this -

```
await expect(page.getByTestId("icon-container")).toBeVisible();
```

Wanted to know if asserting like this above is correct?
Or if below is correct -

```
await expect(page.getByTestId("icon-container").locator("> div"))).toHaveClass(/icon/)
```

Answer (score 0):

> #### How would you choose a good locator?

I think any locator is fine as long they :

- Actually **verify the expected state(visibility of the icon in this scenario)** which can be tested by highlighting it in dev tools.
- Locator is **unique** for obvious
  identification reasons.
- The **Locator itself is not fragile** which can be broken by any small UI changes . For example "class" in my opinion is not an good attribute to depend upon in locator as it may change frequently for various reasons.On the other hand, any visible(to user) text label generally better to depend upon as it may not easily change even though the UI elements under the hood may change drastically.

> In absence of any unique "test id" I also generally look for an
> mysterious quality in locator which I call "**soft & hard"** , by which I mean
> soft enough to endure any UI changes and hard enough to uniquely
> identify the object at the same time.

Considering all of the above I would  go with the first option.